# Database Not Updating from VB.NET Dataset

Tags: database, vb.net

So, I'm trying to create a program in VB.NET that will import an entire Excel file into a new table in Access that has been created beforehand. I'm doing this by creating two datasets: one for all the data from the excel file, one for the database table (which is initially empty). After importing the excel data, I then merge the two datasets. Because the second one is empty, this is effectively copying the first one.

So far, this has all been successful. But, after doing all this and calling the Update command, there are no changes to the database. I've checked, and the datasets are all as they are, but the changes are not copied to the database. Here's the code:

```
Sub ImportSheet2(ByVal ImportFileName As String, ByVal Month As String)
    Dim DBConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ExcelConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DBAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ExcelAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DBDataSet As DataSet
    Dim ExcelDataSet As DataSet
    Dim DatabaseFilePath As String = "C:\Users\alexa\Documents\Alexander's folder\Visual Studio\Computer Science Coursework\Computer Science Coursework\Computer Science Coursework Database.accdb"

    DBConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DatabaseFilePath)
    ExcelConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ImportFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0';")
    DBConnection.Open()
    ExcelConnection.Open()

    ExcelAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", ExcelConnection)
    DBAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM January2018", DBConnection)

    DBDataSet = New DataSet

    ExcelDataSet = New DataSet
    ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet)

    DBDataSet.Merge(ExcelDataSet, preserveChanges:=False)

    Builder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(DBAdapter)
    DBAdapter.UpdateCommand = Builder.GetUpdateCommand()
    DBAdapter.Update(DBDataSet)

    DBConnection.Dispose()
    ExcelConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

No errors occur, so I'm not sure what the issue is here. My Access database also has multiple tables, and I'm not sure how to get it to update just one that I've specified.

For software, I'm using Office 2016, so Access 2016 and Excel 2016. For programming, I'm using VB.NET Framework 4.6.1, from within Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: If you expect the data from a `DataRow` to be inserted into the database when you call `Update`, the `RowState` must be `Added`. Otherwise, you'd be inserting rows all the time. That means that you need to set `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `False` when you retrieve data from Excel and it presumably also means that you need to set `preserveChanges` to `True` when you call merge. If you don't preserve changes then how do you expect to save changes afterwards?

Comment: as @jmcilhinney  advised can you set  DBAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill =false before filling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure it all out after some immensely frustrating time. First, I implemented the suggestions @jmcilhinney gave. Then I realised I was missing a key `OleDBCommandBuilder` function, so I added that in. Finally, I realised that the merge feature was actually completely unnecessary, so I got rid of it and instead imported the Excel data straight to the `DBDataSet`. After this there were some complications with column names not lining up, but after resolving those, it worked!

Of course, this code was horribly inefficient and messy, so after cleaning it up the final code looks like this:

```
Sub ImportSheet2(ByVal ImportFileName As String, ByVal Month As String)
    Dim DBConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ExcelConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DBAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ExcelAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim TransferDataSet As DataSet
    Dim Builder As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder
    Dim DatabaseFilePath As String = "C:\Users\alexa\Documents\Alexander's folder\Visual Studio\Computer Science Coursework\Computer Science Coursework\Computer Science Coursework Database.accdb"

    DBConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DatabaseFilePath) 'These open the two connections to the database and excel file.
    ExcelConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ImportFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0';")
    DBConnection.Open()
    ExcelConnection.Open()

    Try
        ExcelAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", ExcelConnection) 'These create the adapters for the dataset.
        DBAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM January2018", DBConnection)
        ExcelAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False 'This ensures that the changes made will be transferred to the database.

        TransferDataSet = New DataSet 'This makes the dataset that hold the data from the Excel file, ready to be imported to the database.

        ExcelAdapter.Fill(TransferDataSet) 'This imports all the excel data into the dataset, ready to be transferred to the database.

        Builder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(DBAdapter) 'These builder functions execute the SQL commands necessary to update the database.
        Builder.GetUpdateCommand()
        DBAdapter.UpdateCommand = Builder.GetUpdateCommand()
        DBAdapter.Update(TransferDataSet) 'Finally, the dataset is updated with the changes, which are carried over to the database.
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
    End Try

    DBConnection.Dispose()
    ExcelConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

As you can see I put it within a try-catch block, removed the `ExcelDataSet` entirely and renamed `DBDataSet` to `TransferDataSet`, added @jmcilhinney's suggestions, and also added some comments. Hope this helps anyone else having this problem.